# Residues of $\frac{e^{imz}}{1+z^4}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to calculate the residues of  $\frac{e^{imz}}{1+z^4}$. For context, I am calculating  $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{e^{imz}}{1+z^4}dx$ and taking the real part of the integral to calculate  $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\cos mx}{1+x^4}dx$.  I don't necessarily want the answer to the final integral, I would prefer if someone helped me with computing the residues since they seem overly complicated.

We have that $f(z) =\frac{e^{imz}}{1+z^4}$ has simple poles at $e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}, e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}, e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}},$ and $e^{-\frac{3\pi i}{4}}$. Based on my choice of contour, the only poles I need to calculate the residue for are $z=e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$ and $z=e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}}$. We have that \begin{align*} 
Res(f, e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}) &= \frac{exp(ime^{\frac{\pi i}{4}})}{4e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}}}\\
Res(f, e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}}) &= \frac{exp(ime^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}})}{4e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}}
\end{align*}
When I try to apply residue theorem to the desired integral, I get a very complicated expression, and so I am not too sure if the residues I computed are correct. Did I compute the residues correctly?

Comment: What is your path of integration? Do you need all poles, or just the one in the interior of the first quadrant?

Comment: My path of integration is the upper semicircle from $R$ to $-R$ and then the portion of the real line from $-R$ to $R$, so I will need to look at the two poles that I have tried calculating the residues for.